# How to decrypt hostnames of a crypted .ssh/known_hosts with a list of the hostnames?

Tags: ssh, encryption, hostname, ssh-keygen

I try to find a script to **decrypt** (unhash) the ssh hostnames in the known_hosts file **by passing a list of the hostnamses**.

So, to do **exactly the reverse of**:

```
ssh-keygen -H -f known_hosts
```

Or also, to do the same as this if the ssh config HashKnownHosts is set to No:

```
ssh-keygen -R know-host.com -f known_hosts
ssh-keyscan -H know-host.com >> known_hosts
```

But without re-downloading the host key (caused by ssh-keyscan).

Something like:

```
ssh-keygen --decrypt -f known_hosts --hostnames hostnames.txt
```

Where hostnames.txt contains a list of hostnames.

Comment: The hostnames are part of the entries in `known_hosts`. What's to decrypt?

Comment: I mean for a crypted known_hosts file. Where the ssh config HashKnownHosts is to Yes. I modified the title.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Lines in the `known_hosts` file are not encrypted, they are hashed. You can't decrypt them, because they're not encrypted. You can't “unhash” them, because that what a [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) is all about — given the hash, it's impossible¹ to discover the original string. The only way to “unhash” is to guess the original string and verify your guess.

If you have a list of host names, you can pass them to `ssh-keygen -F` and replace them by the host name.

```
while read host comment; do
  found=$(ssh-keygen -F "$host" | grep -v '^#' | sed "s/^[^ ]*/$host/")
  if [ -n "$found" ]; then
    ssh-keygen -R "$host"
    echo "$found" >>~/.ssh/known_hosts
  fi
done <hostnames.txt
```

¹  <sub>In a practical sense, i.e. it would take all the computers existing today longer than the present age of the universe to do it.</sub>

Comment: +1. I have a bash_completion file with a list of ssh files. The host keys for a lot of servers had changed, so I modified your script to give me a list of files which was 1) in my host list (generated) 2) in my known_hosts file (connected to at some point), so to know which  hosts I most likely had to get new host keys for. Ended up with: `grep "^..[dtn]" .ssh/ssh_hosts | while read H; do   [ -n "$(ssh-keygen -F "$H")" ] && echo $H; done`. Basically I knew the host name pattern most likely to be affected, and sent those server names through the script, outputting those in the know_hosts file.

Comment: Good answer. But hashing is just irreversible encryption. Unlike block ciphers and some other forms of reversible encryption, which are reversible encryption.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey Encryption is reversible, by definition.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey Hashing generates a certain kind of signature of a text, not an encryption of a text.  You can't generate the original text from its signature.  You can only guess at the original text, generate its signature, and confirm that the two signatures are the same.

Answer (score 26):

The ssh-keygen(1) man page says for the `-F hostname` option:

> Search for the specified hostname in a known_hosts file, listing any occurrences found. This option is useful to find hashed host names or addresses and may also be used in conjunction with the `-H` option to print found keys in a hashed format.

This seems to be what you want.

Comment: This return the line with the hashed hostname. I want to unhash it to replace it in the known_hosts file. It need a script to parse each line, un-hash it, and then replace it in the known_hosts file.

Comment: @Xorax Yes, but with this command, you can retrieve the hashed hostname, and replace it in the `known_hosts` file with `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

Im finding with these new encrypted files is to simply rm the known_hosts. Copy and paste the text to another location and put a comment above the encrypted known_hosts line about what ip is and the device. Trying to decrypt them just doesn't provide the info you need.